# Using Python 3.7 and 2.x in same IDA

Tags: ida, idapython, python, ida-plugin

I have IDA Pro 7.4 that use with Python 3.7 and I have some IDA-plugin that works only with Python 2.7.

Is there any way to run that Python 2.7 based plugin?

Comment: Have you tried converting it using `2to3`?

Comment: @multithr3at3d can you please what did you mean?

Comment: Python has a program in its standard library to convert Python 2 code to Python 3 https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/2to3.html

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Python 3 and Python 2 in IDA *simultaneously*, but you could switch between them by following instructions in `README_python3.txt` until IDA 8.0, which dropped Python 2 support.

Comment: https://github.com/idapython/src/blob/master/README_python3.txt

Comment: @igor Are you sure that this will work? Because when i run idapythonswitch, it doesn't detect my python2, and that readme says its only for python3.. and the force path requires a python3.dll which that or python2.dll are not present in python2. It gives this error "Cannot determine python library version for "C:\Python27": No "python3.dll" "

Comment: @OneAndOnly Python 2 support has been [removed in IDA 8.0](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/news/8_0/). In theory, you can try building an old version of IDAPython with Python 2 support but I don't know if it will work with 8.x.